# Problem with data format while Importing pandas DF from python into google sheets using df2gsheets

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm using df2gspread to import a certain pandas df into google sheets. The process runs without any issues, but the numeric information which I'd like to manipulate within Gsheets is imported as text. When I use basic math operations with the data stored as text it works, but when I try to use Sheets functions such as sum, average and pretty much anything else, the value returned is always a zero. Also, if I try to manually convert text into numbers within gsheet itself, it doesn't have any effect.

The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import gspread as gs
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g

result = tera.execute_response("select * from table_drive")
df = pd.DataFrame(result)

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'json_gsheets.json', scope)
gc = gs.authorize(credentials)

spreadsheet_key = 'insert_wks_key_here'
wks = 'import'
d2g.upload(df, spreadsheet_key, wks, credentials=credentials, row_names=False,start_cell = 'B3')
```

This inserts the data correctly, but everything is in there irrevocably as text.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Issue

When I saw [the script of df2gspread](https://github.com/maybelinot/df2gspread/blob/01bc46d267c8ea42098f425758930bb28cab0573/df2gspread/df2gspread.py#L24), it seems that the method of `upload` uses the method of [`update_cells()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_cells). In this case, at gspread, the default value of "valueInputOption" is `RAW`. And df2gspread uses the default value. By this, the put number values have the single quote `'` at the top character. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this.

Here, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the script of df2gspread is modified. Please modify [the function of `upload`](https://github.com/maybelinot/df2gspread/blob/01bc46d267c8ea42098f425758930bb28cab0573/df2gspread/df2gspread.py#L24) as follows. In the current stage, I think that there are 3 parts.

#### From:

```
wks.update_cells(cell_list)
```

#### To:

```
wks.update_cells(cell_list, value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the method of "values_update" in gspread is used.

#### Sample script:

```
import pandas as pd
import gspread as gs
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g

result = tera.execute_response("select * from table_drive")
df = pd.DataFrame(result)

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('json_gsheets.json', scope)

gc = gs.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet_key = 'insert_wks_key_here'
wks = 'import'
spreadsheet = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_key)
values = [df.columns.values.tolist()]
values.extend(df.values.tolist())
spreadsheet.values_update(wks, params={'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'}, body={'values': values})
```

- You can see that `USER_ENTERED` is also used in this case.

### References:

- [valueInputOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption)
- [values_update](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=values_update#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_update)

Comment: The pattern 2 has worked flawlessly and is a lot faster than then upload method! Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @Rodolfo Conversani Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.